# NSXML parse image

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsxml

could somebody help me getting the href attribute from this piece of code? 
By using NXMLParser..
ThankYou

```
"<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><a class="lightbox"  title ="1" href="http://www.enlacejudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/12.jpg"><img src="http://www.enlacejudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/12.jpg" alt="" title="1" width="448" height="188" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-59393" /></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering this as string, you can use like -

```
NSString *urlString = nil;
NSString *htmlString = //Your string;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"href=" intoString:nil];
if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"http" intoString:nil];
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@">"];
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&urlString];
}
```

EDIT -

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString { 
    noticias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:encoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    parser.delegate = self; 
    [parser parse]; 
    return self;
}
```

Comment: im sorry rishi, I forgot to say that i am parsing this from the internet, and i am not being able to even read the content:encoded part.

Comment: you are getting this as a response of some url hit?

Comment: no,I am parsing a huge document with nsxmlparser, I was able to parse everything except this part...

Comment: -(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
 noticias  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSURL *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSData *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 parser   = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    
 parser.delegate = self;
 [parser parse];
 return self;
}
and then

Comment: - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    
    
 if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
 {
  noticia = [Noticia alloc];
        [noticias addObject:noticia];
 }



    
}

Comment: @user1179587 - try with above code posted in answer, hope it will give you proper string values.